# Freezing Ubuntu 21.10 on startup

Tags: boot

I just upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 because of security updates etc. Now 21.04 was fast, nice smoother. Initially on search I found that upgrading the kernel may help making 21.10 faster. Now I'm stuck with this image for more than 30min and counting. [image]

Comment: Some of your details are not clear and possibly missing. Is it correct that you upgraded the kernel *after* the upgrade because you were trying to solve some other problem? If so, how exactly did you upgrade the kernel? Are you now using an unsupported kernel? Which version?  Can you not boot the older (supported) kernel?  And what was the original problem that you were trying to fix?

Comment: After upgrading from older kernel 5.13.. To the latest. Upon restart, the system freezing just after putting the password.

Comment: Sorry, I got carried away. After several restarts, I managed to login, the reason I got carried away. I upgraded to kernel 5.15, when I got the freezing. Even the restarts were very slow. I managed to update the system and says it's up to date. My original problem was that trying to update 21.04, I got a message that security updates were not available so advice was to got to 21.10.after upgrade to the 21.10 that's when it got slow. How can I make sure it's fast enough and does not freeze. Thank you for your support.

Comment: To solve that problem we would need to identify what is causing it. It sounds like there were issues that preexisted even before the upgrade. In that case, a new installation may be the best path forward. It can be hard to diagnose these kinds of issues if they are not associated with a specific behavior, especially if they were a problem before a system upgrade.

Comment: Cool. I'll do that. Thanks